# Backup And Sync - application dosn't open. Mac Mojave

Tags: macos, google-drive-api, backup, drive

When I try and open the application nothing happens, no menu bar/windows, nothing.
I have tried uninstalling - reinstalling.. I have checked the permissions, nothing works.
I tried opening the program using terminal to see if there were any error messages and i got this.

```
​(base) Mac-Pro:~ ash$ /Applications/Backup\ and\ Sync.app/Contents/MacOS/Backup\ and\ Sync 
/Applications/Backup and Sync.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python2.7/site-packages.zip/wx/_core.py:16633: UserWarning: wxPython/wxWidgets release number mismatch
2020-05-14 17:04:47.318 Backup and Sync[1538:17017] GsyncAppDeletegate.py : Finder debug level logs : False
```

I am not really sure how to decipher that. "wxPython/wxWidgets release number mismatch"?

​also when I look in activity monitor the process has this weird white box log.

[image]

Not really sure how best to either identify the problem or solve it. Any idea's, or pointers/steps i can use to help me figure out what the problem is would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: Has this been resolved? I am experiencing the same problem